# How do I import login to my existing project

Tags: android

I have an android project without a login screen, I have downloaded and extracted a login lbrary from github and imported to android studio but as a different project, how do I let the login run before my actual project

Comment: It would be useful if you could show a [mcve] of the code you have.

Comment: I'm having issues determining what you are actually asking for. Do you have a valid login Activity, and are you asking how to use 2 Activities in a single application, or what? This is where @cricket_007's note is important... It is easier for us to give you an example with code you are already using. Without that I would just be providing template code with an updated **Android Manifest**, which loads an Activity before your Main Activity